# Nginx - allow maximum third level domains

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a website:

```
example.com
```

I want to allow only example.com and any **dynamic** third level subdomain:

```
test.example.com
test1.example.com
test-test.example.com
```

If subdomain level is more than 3:

```
test.test.example.com
test.test.test.example.com
```

...it should not reach my app which is located behind that proxy.

I tried to do this:

```
server_name example.com ~^[0-9a-z-]+\.example\.com$;
```

There were no problem with Nginx configuration checker, but that regex didn't work for me. Is that regular expression correct?

Comment: Do you have a "catch-all" server block to handle requests that do not match the regular expression?

Comment: @RichardSmith, you mean, `server { server_name _; ... }` ?

Comment: No, use `default_server`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names).